# Asymptote (Little-o) Notation in Tensor Calculus

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, tensors

Recently, my professor used little-o notation in writing out tensor functions, and I am having difficulty understanding what it really means. For instance, say $\bf{H}$ and $\bf{U}$ are tensor fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$. He has made statements like:
$$ \bf{U} = \frac{1}{2}\bf{H}\bf{H}^{T} + o(|\bf{H}|)$$

To me it seems like there must be a typo and the little-o term should be $o(\bf{H})$. Either way, I don't understand the concept being used. Any help or references would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Possibly expression $\bf{U} - \frac{1}{2}\bf{H}\bf{H}^{T} \in o(|\bf{H}|)$ have some sense in your lectures. Why not ask your professor directly?

Comment: I have asked him directly; he tried to relate it to the way little-o is used in Taylor series, but I don't think he knew all of the details. I asked on here to see if the notation is standard in any math fields (the class where this notation is being used is a continuum mechanics course).